# Issue when attempting to edit/change SKU for one of my products

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, sql

Whenever I try editing my products and changing or editing the SKU, I keep getting this.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webadmin_exc2_legacy.autosuggest_batch' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `autosuggest_batch` AS `main_table` WHERE (`product_id` = '33') AND (`store_id` = '0')
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a **autosuggest** module that has not been installed properly.

Disable Compilation and flush cache then:

Either re-install extension
or
Disable Extension in app/etc/modules
or
Remove Extension Completely.

Comment: I disabled autosuggest module in config and still not working. How can I disable compilation?

Comment: System > Tools > Compilation > Disable

Comment: If this corrects the problem then System > Tools > Compilation > Run Compilation Process

Answer (score 1):

remove the autosuggest xml file located in app/etc/modules. Restart Apache due to xml change

Comment: Do you mean "Refresh cache" instead of "Restart Apache"? ;)